# Build argument in quay.io

Tags: docker, dockerfile, coreos, quay.io

I have set up a private repo in quay.io
Also, set up a build trigger which is working as expected.

The only problem I'm facing is with the build argument.
My Dockerfile requires a build argument and that's the reason why currently the build is failing in quay.io.

So is there any way I can set build argument in quay.io

Comment: what kind of arguments trying to pass ? please add more info about the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Quay.io does not currently support parsing of build arguments to build nodes. There's no mechanism to do so.